# Lagrange Polynomial to estimate the derivatives of a function

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, error-function, lagrange-interpolation

We have the following question for our homework. I'm completely lost on what to do. I have no idea how to compute the error of the derivative or how to proceed from there. I've tried googling Lagrange polynomials to estimate derivatives but haven't really found anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't estimate derivatives without additional hypotheses. Consider for example $\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: This is the homework. For estimating the derivative, I'm guessing I look at the polynomial and differentiate it. But don't know what to do beyond that